# Exponential Smoothing Average

Tags: python, pandas, average

I was going through this website to find out more about exponential smoothing average, but wasn't sure about 1 section of the code.

```
import pandas, numpy as np
ewma = pandas.stats.moments.ewma

# make a hat function, and add noise
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
x = np.hstack((x,x[::-1]))
x += np.random.normal( loc=0, scale=0.1, size=200 )
plot( x, alpha=0.4, label='Raw' )

# take EWMA in both directions with a smaller span term
fwd = ewma( x, span=15 ) # take EWMA in fwd direction
bwd = ewma( x[::-1], span=15 ) # take EWMA in bwd direction
c = np.vstack(( fwd, bwd[::-1] )) # lump fwd and bwd together
c = np.mean( c, axis=0 ) # average

# regular EWMA, with bias against trend
plot( ewma( x, span=20 ), 'b', label='EWMA, span=20' )

# "corrected" (?) EWMA
plot( c, 'r', label='Reversed-Recombined' )
```

What I don't get is this section

```
# take EWMA in both directions with a smaller span term
fwd = ewma( x, span=15 ) # take EWMA in fwd direction
bwd = ewma( x[::-1], span=15 ) # take EWMA in bwd direction
c = np.vstack(( fwd, bwd[::-1] )) # lump fwd and bwd together
c = np.mean( c, axis=0 ) # average
```

could someone please kindly explain what is going on here?

The full source of the website is: http://connor-johnson.com/2014/02/01/smoothing-with-exponentially-weighted-moving-averages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the main issue here is what `bwd[::-1]` means? See additional comments added.

```
# take EWMA in both directions with a smaller span term

fwd = ewma( x, span=15 ) # take EWMA in fwd direction
## This part should not be a problem, right?

bwd = ewma( x[::-1], span=15 ) # take EWMA in bwd direction
## x[::-1] means to go thr x, from end to beginning(!), with a step of -1
## (hence it is going from the back to the front)

c = np.vstack(( fwd, bwd[::-1] )) # lump fwd and bwd together
c = np.mean( c, axis=0 ) # average
## Then we reverse ewma into a beginning-to-end order
## and take the average of fwd and bwd
## IMO, better written just as:

#c =  0.5*(fwd + bwd[::-1])
```

The idea is, in the forward EWMA, the current value is affected, but increasingly less and less so, by earlier values.  The backward EWMA, on the other hand, are affected by the later values.  Finally, by taking the average of both the forward and backward EWMA, you create something that is affected by the surrounding values (if we call them so), but increasingly less and less so as you moving away from the current position.

Comment: Thanks! and yes, i was having issues with `bwd[::-1]`.. But good explanation!

Comment: I have one other question. If I want to replicate this, would my below code for fwd and bwd be correct?

`fwd = pd.ewma(df['Close'], span=20) 
        bwd = pd.ewma(df['Close'][::-1], span=20)`