Removing Spikes from Spectra
The question is; how to remove spikes from spectroscopy data, in an efficient way, using Numpy or SciPy only.
[Aside, before going further, it may be necessary to mention that the question with a similar title at, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556487, is not the same question.  The data has characteristics and the answers posted there are not appropriate to this data.]
For context, there about 1000 of these per data set and there are perhaps 20 data sets that we need to process in various ways.  So, the time to load and clean each spectrum is important.
Below there is a code that removes the spikes but takes too long.  So, the question might be rephrased "how do I speed up this code?"   I originally thought to express it one or two lines in numpy, but so far have not worked out how to do that.
There is a median filter in SciPy's.  So far, that median filter is not working well for this task.
Following is an example of a spectrum that might be read from a spectrometer that has a linear CCD.
Notice there are spikes. (Where these spikes come from is interesting, but not directly relevant to the question.)

Now here is a code that I wrote, that removes the spikes.
def spectrum_excursion_filter( data, span=13, threshold=2., passes=2 ):

datalen = len(data)

x = np.linspace(0,span,span,endpoint=False)

for n, d in enumerate(data):

    if n < span:
        n1 = 0
        n2 = n1 + span;
    elif datalen - n < span:
        n1 = datalen - span
        n2 = datalen
    else:
        n1 = n - int(span/2)
        n2 = n + span


    #segment = copy.deepcopy(data[n1:n2])
    segment = data[n1:n2]
    median_ = np.median(segment)
    stdev_  = np.std(segment)

    m = passes - 1
    while m > 0:
        idx = np.where(np.abs(segment-median_)<threshold*stdev_)
        signal = np.median(segment[idx])
        stdev_ = np.std(segment[idx])
        m -= 1

    if abs(d - median_) > threshold * stdev_:
        data[n] = median_

return data

And here is the result.   It does a good job.  But it takes 3 seconds.  So that is 3000 seconds per data set.  And that is far too long.

The raw data for the above images can be obtained here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19AyVF1cTl2JXHGWswUY0fBF735l4lmYz?usp=sharing

The folder linked is "empty"...

@XenonPy oh, yes of course, apologies, i am still setting everything up.   It is there now

What needs to be preserved about the data and what can change?

Is that plot a plot of the linked data? The values in the linked data are much larger than you show.

It is done. Thank you.

@jared   Yes, there is a dark frame subtraction, I forgot about that.  I think it does not change the problem in any significant way.   If you want that scale, You could pick a section of baseline where there is no significant spectral intensity, take a median and subtract and get a similar scale.

A while ago, I came across a paper that was dealing with the removal of outliers in spectroscopy data: https://doi.org/10.1107/S1600577521003611. I haven't tried to reproduce the algorithm presented in the paper but thought it may be useful to mention that work.

This algorithm selects 50% more elements than span, because it looks half a span backward, plus a full span forward. Is that intentional?

Your code modify data in-place. Thus, it is nearly impossible to make it faster with Numpy because most functions operate on items in an independent way. Numpy cannot speed up a (very specific) sequence of dependent operations on items of the same array (except common generic cases like cumsum or cumprod). Is this intended? Can we assume data[n] = median_ do not impact the result (certainly wrong)? If no, then I am afraid this function cannot be optimized without changing the algorithm significantly (especially "using Numpy or SciPy only").

"So far, that median filter is not working well for this task" Can you please elaborate why?

@JérômeRichard    I think it may be that where the median fails, the spike is more than one pixel wide.   Realizing that now, maybe the scipy median filter will work with a footprint something like [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]

@JérômeRichard   Also, thank you for pointing out the problem about modifying code in place

@NickODell   Yes, intentional.

@braunlee   Thank you for the cite.  One thing that seemed interesting right away, is that in 2021 we scan still publish papers on de-glitching data.  (Savitzky Golan was published in 1964 for example).    The other thing is that I  was a synchrotron scientist too, many years ago.  So I am always happy to see one cited.

@JérômeRichard   your comment proved quite fruitful.  Not doing it in place gave the needed speedup.  Thank you.

I found that maybe you can try to use the rolling pandas' function to denoise the data, there are some other denoising algorithms, but I found this as the easiest to implement.

You can try to increase the windows parameter, to get a smoother distribution.
Documentation of the function: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html
the code that I implement:
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("data/temp.data", engine='python',
                   skiprows=1, skipfooter=3, names=['values'])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.set_size_inches(10, 5)

ax1.set_xlabel('Wavelength')
ax2.set_xlabel('Wavelength')

ax1.set_ylabel('Intensity')
ax2.set_ylabel('Intensity')

ax1.plot(data['values'])
ax2.plot(data.rolling(window=10).mean())

ax1.grid(True)
ax2.grid(True)

plt.show()


A mean is far from being great to correct big spikes like in the OP plot. A median filter is far better suited for that. Besides, the OP explicitly stated "using Numpy or SciPy only".

@JérômeRichard You are right, if you want to solve the problem using the pandas library, you can change the call to the mean() function to median(), to obtain slightly better results.

Admirable, but there are still spikes.   Maybe it looks better with a median?

Building on @alan-menchaca answer and the paper I referenced in the comments below the question, here is a solution that may work by only filtering big spikes and replacing their values with their median.
This solution does use pandas since it has a rolling median built-in, which I am not aware numpy or scipy do. The data processing portion takes about 0.006 seconds.
# Import modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy
import time

# Load the data
data = np.loadtxt('temp.txt')

t1 = time.time()
# Smooth the data to determine
## Savitzy-Golay Parameters
window_length = 50
poly_order = 3

smooth = savgol_filter(data,window_length,poly_order)

# Calculate residuals
res = np.abs(data-smooth)

# Normalize residuals by rolling window
# Transform to pd data frame to make use of "rolling" - center the window to look back and forward

rolling_window = 25
respd = pd.DataFrame(res)
norm = respd.rolling(window=rolling_window,center=True).median()
spikes = np.divide(res,np.array(norm[0]))

# Filter out the spikes to replace
datapd = pd.DataFrame(data)
averages = datapd.rolling(window=rolling_window,center=True).median()

# Set threshold and replace spikes with mean of surrounding rolling window
thres = 2.5

filtered_data = copy.deepcopy(data)
for idx,spike in enumerate(np.where(spikes>thres)[0]):
    filtered_data[spike] = np.array(averages[0])[spike]

t2 = time.time()
print('Time',t2-t1)

# Plot some data
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(filtered_data)



This solution is better than the two others so far. I think you can replace the rolling function of Pandas with np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view of Numpy though using it correctly might be a bit tedious.

Yes, without pandas please.   But anyway, there is still a spike to the right of bin 1400.  The median may fail because it is more than one pixel wide.

"it has a rolling median built-in, which I am not aware numpy or scipy do." SciPy has this - it's called median_filter.

Another possibility is to find the peaks using scipy's find_peak and replace the data between the peak bases by its median:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

data = np.loadtxt('temp.data')
data -= np.median(data[:10])
plt.plot(data)

peaks, props = signal.find_peaks(data, prominence=4, wlen=13)
for i, peak in enumerate(peaks):
    idx = slice(props['left_bases'][i], props['right_bases'][i])
    data[idx] = np.median(data[idx])
plt.plot(data)


This is about 500 times faster than the original solution.

That is pretty cool that it actually works.  Nice job.

Here are a few options.

Rolling mean (using numpy's np.convolve based on this answer)
Scipy's scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter1d
Scipy's scipy.signal.wiener

All three of these methods are fast (see timings below), though their results aren't as good as yours.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import wiener
from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter1d

plt.close("all")

def rolling_mean(x, window_length):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621523/12131013
    return np.convolve(x, np.ones(window_length)/window_length, mode="valid")

data = np.loadtxt("temp.data", dtype=np.float64)

rolling_mean_res = rolling_mean(data, 11)
uniform_filter_res = uniform_filter1d(data, 11)
wiener_res = wiener(data, mysize=11)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,5))
axes = axes.flatten()
axes[0].plot(data)
axes[1].plot(rolling_mean_res)
axes[2].plot(uniform_filter_res)
axes[3].plot(wiener_res)
titles = ["Original", "Rolling Mean", "Uniform Filter", "Wiener"]
for ax, title in zip(axes, titles):
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.grid()
fig.tight_layout()

Results:

Timings:
%timeit rolling_mean(data, 11)
5.7 μs ± 156 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit uniform_filter1d(data, 11)
5.32 μs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit wiener(data, mysize=11)
46.7 μs ± 1.56 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)


When a signal contains big spikes (i.e. impulse noise), a mean is a bad filter. Indeed, even though it attenuate the spikes, it tends to significantly distort the underlying signal. A median filter don't (except when spikes are large or when the window is too small). uniform_filter1d is basically a rolling mean. wiener should be better but it tends to blur the signal like a rolling mean and it is not so great for spikes.
